# Where to get the short wire of the cantilever brake?

Tags: brakes, cable

I was riding my bike and rear brake fell apart. As a result I lost the short wire of the cantilever brake, or at least that what it seems to be called. Where can I buy that short cable please ?[image] Here is the same piece of the front brake:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon or your local bike shop.

Here's a double ended (you can cut into one or two depending on length you need) on Amazon: [BRAKE PART STRADDLE CABLE ACTION ROAD 2-ENDS 110MM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047MDL8K).

Enjoy!

Comment: I spent 1 hour searching and nothing. Thanks man!

Comment: Amazingly, the link is still good

Answer (score 7):

I know an answer has been selected, but I wanted to post this here for future reference.

First - the common name for that type part is a "straddle cable" or a "link wire" depending on the variations or the manufacturer.

Second - my primary source (after my LBS) for less-common parts, especially parts for older bikes or the bike-shaped objects the neighborhood kids want me to fix is [Loose Screws](http://www.loosescrews.com).

Here is their [Straddle Cable](http://www.loosescrews.com/Cable/Straddle-Cable-and-Link-Wire/) page.